# Is it possible for map to mutate object?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a very strange case which indicates that either **map function mutates object** or **lodash incorrectly clones the object.** This piece of code is just a sample: a function that takes an object as an argument and  returns a copy of it using cloneDeep from lodash. Then I use this object to generate a chart.

```
const copyObject = data => {
  const copy = _.cloneDeep(data);

  const dataWithIndexes = copy.nodes.map((node, index) => {
    node.index = index;
    return node;
  });

  return copy;
};

export const copiedData = copyObject(sampleData);
```

Entry data in this case is an object with arrays of objects:

```
{
  nodes: [
    { name: "transactions.main", layer: 0 },
    ...
  ],
  links: [
    { source: 3, target: 3, value: 4 },
    ...
  ]
}
```

As you can see map inside function is not used at all and this is the point. When I am using original, unmodified object within my chart generate function it works fine, when I am copying the object with function shown above, it doesn't work, BUT when I comment this **dataWithIndexes** variable it starts working again. Is it possible in any way that map mutates the copied object? Or maybe it's lodash's fault? It may clone the object incorrectly, but on the other hand I only use the map on it, it doesn't modify it in any way.

Maybe anyone can help me solving this riddle T_T

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are modifying the `node` object parameter in the `map(...)` callback by overwriting its `index` property: `node.index = index`. This way the original object in the array is getting mutated although it returns a new array.

This would still happen even though you are not using the `dataWithIndexes` that is because the `map(...)` is still run and when it does it mutates the objects in the `copy.node` array with the new values of the `index` in the callback.

To avoid it, make a copy of the `node` object parameter in the map call and assign the new `index` there and then return it from the callback:

```
const dataWithIndexes = copy.nodes.map((node, index) => {
    return {...node, index};
});
```